# Paypal order information / data capture

Tags: paypal

I manage a charity's website, and they've asked me to place some products for sale through paypal onto a webpage.

I could place some Paypal buy now buttons, but they've asked me to capture customer information like name and address, so we know where to send the products to.

Is this information available to us from the Paypal website?

If not, could you suggest a way to introduce a simple form to capture such information as part of the ordering process?

I'm not a programmer, just a web designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These information are available in your paypal account too, but PayPal sends you an email notification every time a transaction is done. So if you don't want to struggle with programming, this is a good solution.

Here are a few link you should check out (the first one is about the customer experience, the second about managing transactions):

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_buynow_buttons#id089UG0HI0XW

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_buynow_buttons#id089UI0S40TS